# How to manage select box (representing a relation between entities) with Meteor React?

Tags: reactjs, meteor, web-component, meteor-react

I'm using Meteor/React to build a social App. Users are related to others by a ManyToOne relation (a user have a representative).

So I made a Member Component which return a template with a form inside it to select the representative, and created an API to execute some actions on users.

Everything works quite well but the delete function do not update the client side (I opened another window with the application).

I feel like i'm missing the point with the Component notion, should that select box be a Component too ?

Here is Member.jsx

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

import { Members } from '../api/members.js';

// Member component - represents a single member item
export default class Member extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.select_representant).value = this.props.member.representant;
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.select_representant).value = this.props.member.representant;
  }

  setRepresentant() {
    Meteor.call('members.setRepresentant', this.props.member._id, 'oo');
  }

  deleteThisMember() {
    Meteor.call('members.remove', this.props.member._id);
  }

  renderRepresentants() {
    let representants = Members.find().fetch();
    return representants.map((representant) => (
      <option key={representant._id} value={representant._id}>{representant.pseudo}</option>
    ));
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Find the text field via the React ref
    const representantId = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.select_representant).value.trim();
    const representant = Members.findOne({ _id: representantId });

    Meteor.call('members.setRepresentant', this.props.member._id, representantId);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>

        <h3 className="text">
          {this.props.member.pseudo} <button className="delete" onClick={this.deleteThisMember.bind(this)}>&times;</button>
        </h3>

        <form className="form-horizontal">
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="select_representant" className="col-sm-3 control-label">Représentant</label>
            <div className="col-sm-7">
              <select ref="select_representant" className="form-control custom-select" name="select_representant" onChange={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                {this.renderRepresentants()}
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and members.jsx

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';

export const Members = new Mongo.Collection('members');

Meteor.methods({
  'members.insert'(pseudo) {
    check(pseudo, String);

    Members.insert({
      pseudo
    });
  },
  'members.remove'(memberId) {
    check(memberId, String);

    Members.remove(memberId);
    represented = Members.find({ representant: memberId }).fetch();
    for(representedItem in represented){
      Members.update(representedItem, { $set: { representant: null } });
    }
  },
  'members.setRepresentant'(memberId, representantId) {
    check(memberId, String);
    check(representantId, String);

    Members.update(memberId, { $set: { representant: representantId } });
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
deleteThisMember() {
  Meteor.call('members.remove', this.props.member._id);
  renderRepresentants();
}
```

Or, you tried to put your member list on thie.props?

Comment: I didn't even think about calling this method >< No I didn't try props. Right now I'm looking for inspiration in the [meteor/todos react exemple](https://github.com/meteor/todos/tree/react), looks strong !

Answer (score 1):

Since you query for the `Members` within the React render function, it's not reactive with the changes in the database. You need to use `createContainer` from the `react-meteor-data` to see the changes in your front-end:

```js
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
...
export default class Member extends Component {
  ...
  renderRepresentants() {
    let representants = this.props.representants;
    ...
  }
...
}

createContainer(() => {
  return {
    representants: Members.find().fetch()
  };
}, Member);
```

Now the query should be properly reactively updated when there are changes in the `Members` collection.